# CRM WebAPI 2016 with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-web-api, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to use node.js with CRM 2016 webAPI .
I'm building a service using node.js which will be running in background and part of it is it will retrieve the events form CRM using WebAPI.
The problem is I don't know how to authenticate using username/password and we don't have O365 nor Azure.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Do you have CRM on premise or CRM online?

Comment: On Premise, Actually a company manages and hosts it for us but it's not hosted by Microsoft cloud. @lazarus

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [DynamicsNode](https://github.com/crisfervil/DynamicsNode) on Git. It has helpers already made for accessing CRM from Node.

Comment: thx but there is no any information regarding to 2016 in this project. I still need to know how to use username and password with WebAPI 2016 CRM.

Comment: based on the README, it looks like it has been tested with CRM online, so it might work for 2016, maybe raise an issue on Git?